# SQL Group two columns and select recent date/timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table called phone_messages. This is an example query that I have written. What I am trying to do is group together rows that have character_id 22 or target_character_id 22. Because in each phone_message stored in the database these is two entries. Basically phone conversations. What I am trying to do is group get the last message send in each of the groups.

My Original Query:

```
SET @character_id = 22;
SET @t = 'text';

SELECT character_id, target_character_id, message, `type`, MAX(`date`) date FROM
    `phone_messages`
WHERE
    (
        `character_id`=@character_id
    ) AND `type`=@t
GROUP BY
    character_id, target_character_id
```

---

```
character_id | target_character_id | message | type | date
"22"    "33"    "correct"   "text"  "2020-08-25 23:28:31"
"33"    "22"    "perfect see you then"  "text"  "2020-08-25 23:28:43"
"57"    "22"    "where is this mega mall" "text" "2020-09-05 19:05:25"
"22"    "57"    "the tool shop down south"  "text"  "2020-09-05 19:05:45"
```

---

My desired output for this would be

```
character_id | target_character_id | message | type | date
"33"    "22"    "perfect see you then"  "text"  "2020-08-25 23:28:43"
"22"    "57"    "the tool shop down south"  "text"  "2020-09-05 19:05:45"
```

---

How would I go about doing this? Sorry for any lack of understanding in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm

- For each 'pair' of callers (one of who is "22")
- You would like to get the latest text which went either way (either to or from 22)

The answer here uses the following approach

- For each row, determine the other party (this is called `second_character_id` in the query)
- For each other party, order the 'text' rows based on the date sent
- Get the latest row for each party

```
WITH Call_list AS
    (SELECT *,
        @character_id AS `primary_character_id`,
        CASE 
            WHEN `character_id` = @character_id THEN `target_character_id`
            ELSE `character_id` END AS `second_character_id`
    FROM
        `phone_messages`
    WHERE
        (`character_id`= @character_id OR `target_character_id`= @character_id)
        AND (`type`= @t )
    ),
Sorted_Call_List AS
    (SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY `primary_character_id`, `second_character_id` 
                ORDER BY `Date` DESC
                ) AS char_rn
    FROM Call_list
    )
SELECT `character_id`, `target_character_id`, `message`, `type`, `date`
FROM   Sorted_Call_List
WHERE  char_rn = 1;
```

With this answer I also included the `primary_character_id` - which in this case is always 22 - in case you wanted to expand it to have multiple people.

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=278d17c1b524927c39af6127e8d696f5) with the data setup and approach.

Note that there is an additional query at the bottom there - that was my previous attempt where I misunderstood the requirements. In that answer, it finds the latest 'incoming' and latest 'outgoing' text to/from 22, regardless of who they came from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent message for each pair, regardless of ordering, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`:

```
SET @character_id = 22;
SET @t = 'text';

SELECT pm.*
FROM (SELECT pm.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(character_id, target_character_id), GREATEST(character_id, target_character_id)
                              ORDER BY date DESC
                             ) as seqnum
      FROM phone_messages pm
      WHERE character_id = @character_id AND
            type = @t
     ) pm
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```